# Can I use "after" before the afternoon? Is it grammatically right?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can I use a sentence like "I will it see it after afternoon"?
I mean can I use "after" before the afternoon. Is it grammatically right?

Comment: _I will see it late afternoon_ could be what you mean.

Comment: "After this afternoon" (or "after the afternoon" or whatever) would be better, since there is an afternoon every day, and your original sentence doesn't specify which one.  That said, it sounds ugly, even if it's gramatically correct.

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure if that's an Americanism, but _I will see it late this afternoon_ sounds far more idiomatic to my British ears.

Answer (score 4):

*After afternoon* is the evening, so a native speaker would normally say 'I will it see it this evening'.

Comment: I don't think *will it see it* is grammatical. It might be good if you point that out.

Comment: @Noah It's archaic: *I will* can mean *I want* or *I decree*, and the sentence could be expressed "I decree that it will see it this evening," where there are two antecedent nouns to identify the pronouns. That said, it's probably not what the OP intended.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, note the extra ‘it’: I will **it** see it this evening.

Comment: Thanks. Missed that. Perhaps OP can tell us whether it was intentional.